# Is there a way to turn JSON field in postgreSQL to dotted array?

Tags: postgresql

In postgresql is there a way to turn a tables column, who's type is JSON into a dotted array?

```
{
  "quote" : {
    "daysRemaining" : "365"
  },
  "estimate" : {
    "coveredEquipment" : {
      "kickerMotorInsurance" : "No",
      "vesselEngineType" : "None\/Other",
      "trailerInsurance" : "No",
      "dinghyInsurance" : "No"
    }
  }
}
```

Expected result would be:

```
{
     "quote.daysRemaining" => "365",
     "estimate.coveredEquipment.vesselEngineType" => "None/Other",
     "estimate.coveredEquipment.trailerInsurance" => "No",
     "estimate.coveredEquipment.kickerMotorInsurance" => "No",
     "estimate.coveredEquipment.dinghyInsurance" => "No"
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I used a recursive query to get the json keys glue by a dot and their related value. My query can help you get an idea of how to solve the problem, but I think it could be improve.

I used `json_each()` function to expands the top-level `JSON` object into a set of key/value pairs.

```
WITH RECURSIVE q AS (SELECT (json_each(data)).key AS k, (json_each(data)).value AS v 
                      FROM t

                      UNION ALL
                     
                      SELECT k || '.' || (json_each(v)).key AS k, (json_each(v)).value AS v
                      FROM q
                      WHERE json_typeof(v) = 'object'
)

SELECT *
FROM q
WHERE json_typeof(v) != 'object';
```

Output:

| k | v |
| --- | --- |
| quote.daysRemaining | "365" |
| estimate.coveredEquipment.kickerMotorInsurance | "No" |
| estimate.coveredEquipment.vesselEngineType | "None/Other" |
| estimate.coveredEquipment.trailerInsurance | "No" |
| estimate.coveredEquipment.dinghyInsurance | "No" |

Or you can get a `JSON` object:

```
WITH RECURSIVE q AS (SELECT (json_each(data)).key AS k, (json_each(data)).value AS v 
                      FROM t

                      UNION ALL
                     
                      SELECT k || '.' || (json_each(v)).key AS k, (json_each(v)).value AS v
                      FROM q
                      WHERE json_typeof(v) = 'object'
)

SELECT json_object_agg(k, v)
FROM q
WHERE json_typeof(v) != 'object';
```

Output:

```
{ 
  "quote.daysRemaining" : "365", 
  "estimate.coveredEquipment.kickerMotorInsurance" : "No", 
  "estimate.coveredEquipment.vesselEngineType" : "None\/Other", 
  "estimate.coveredEquipment.trailerInsurance" : "No", 
  "estimate.coveredEquipment.dinghyInsurance" : "No" 
}
```